# Merging multiple csv files into one excel sheet

Tags: java

I need to prepare a java tool where i need to merge multiple CSV  files into a single excel sheet . Now each of these csv files merged should represent a separate worksheet in the combined excel sheet . Can anyone please help me on how to proceed with the development of this tool and the logic involved in this .

Comment: We might be able to help but what have you tried so far?

Comment: To create an excel sheet, you would have to use a library. One free library I've already worked with is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org). Have a special look at [HSSFWorkBook.createSheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#createSheet%28%29). Examples and tutorials should be available on the internet - for example [this one](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-to-an-excel-file-using-poi.html)

Comment: Uptil now i have written java class which can fetch data from multiple csv files . now after fetching i don't know  how to combine this data of multiple csv files into one complete excel sheet . This excel sheet should contain all the csv files as seaparate worksheets with thier names .

Comment: read all the rows from all csv , store in a single list and write the single list into excel , have you tried so

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [jexcelapi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Quoting from their website

> Java Excel API is a mature, open source java API enabling developers to read, write, and modifiy Excel spreadsheets dynamically. Now java developers can read Excel spreadsheets, modify them with a convenient and simple API, and write the changes to any output stream (e.g. disk, HTTP, database, or any socket).

I have used this beginners tutorial before: [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html)